# What to use to get data from OpenFIGI API to store into AWS or Snowflake?

Tags: amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, finance, google-finance, google-finance-api

I am trying to get help on what to use to get data from OpenFIGI API to store into AWS or Snowflake?

https://www.openfigi.com/api

I would like to build a form or input sheet to be able to input the POST /v2/search Request Format for OpenFIGI and send the API request.

I need help figuring out how to get the input built and where to stage the return data in AWS or Snowflake so I can attach it to other tables.

Thanks for any help or quickstarts that may help me along.

Best,
PJ

Comment: This question, although is straightforward, it needs many considerations like how much you need to scale, how easy you want to develop and so on. Few options: 1) Create the form in Google Spreadsheet ([more](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/18670422?hl=en) and each submit configure it to do that POST; 2) Create the form in your website (probably), use AWS SQS for the messaging part of the form, and create a lambda for your API. There are many more options, but wanted to give you an idea how to refine your question. Document better what you want to achieve and what path you took.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at ETL tools that are able to connect to API and Snowflake.  Matillion, for example, offers this ability.